# Do we have azure native library to connect to redis from java?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, redis

I'm trying to rotate the primary key of redis and check whether application restart is required in order to fetch the updated key or not.

For this purpose, I thought of using the azure native library to connect to redis from springboot application.

Do we have any azure sdk for redis for redis connection ? I've come across the below dependency which is not native to azure .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What do you call "native azure", any of the Java clients will do the job Jedis, Lettuce ... (see https://redis.io/clients#java ) - Jedis that you have selected is perfect and you can integrate it with Spring

Comment: What I meant native to Azure is to use azure specific libraries for redis to connect from java. Do we have any specific libraries ?

Comment: You do not need such a thing, any of the Redis clients will work perfectly with Azure cache. This is one of the benefits of having Redis "everywhere". I am inviting you to look at Jedis, Lettuce, or Redisson. I am personally using Jedis most of the time.